# Can I use multiple shapes in one Android drawable?

Tags: android, layout, drawable

What I'm trying to do is define a common background for use in a LinearLayout which frequents my application on many of its Activitys.  This particular layout is a header that shows on the top of each activity.

What I'm trying to do is create a drawable that fills the linearlayout with a gradient and has a horizontal line below the gradient.

Does anyone know if this is possible or do I have to do this sort of thing only with nested layouts.

My attemptat the drawable xml is

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#AA000000" android:endColor="#AA333333"
        android:angle="270" />
</shape>
</item>
<item>
<shape android:shape="line">
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:dashWidth="1dp" android:dashGap="2dp" />
    <size android:height="5dp" />
</shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Drawable accepts multiple shapes, (defined always in others files) if i understand your question maybe you can do a Layer drawable (this draws multiple underlying drawables on top of each other)

i write this here, so, i dont tested, but try this and read this fantastic documentation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_7"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_1"/>
    </layer-list>
```

[the android complete xml resources](http://idunnolol.com/android/drawables.html#layer-list_item)

cheers

Comment: is it also possible to set them one below the other (in the Y coordinate) ?

Comment: Add the android namespace to each item <item xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ... /> and its perfect

Comment: Good point @Philiiiiiipp. However, adding the namespace in the layer-list would suffice as opposed to adding it to each item in the list. Like so: <layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">.

Comment: Can anyone have solution to create shape one below the other (in the Y coordinate)?

Answer (score 5):

Use **gravity** to set your **items** in **layer-list**.

```
    for vertical orientation use:
    android:gravity="top"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:gravity="bottom"
```

```
    for horizontal orientation use:
    android:gravity="left"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:gravity="right"
```

```
<layer-list
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
          <item>
                <bitmap
                   android:src="@drawable/top_img"
                   android:gravity="top"/>
          </item>
          <item>
                <bitmap
                   android:src="@drawable/center_img"
                   android:gravity="center"/>
          </item>
          <item>
                <bitmap
                   android:src="@drawable/bottom_img"
                   android:gravity="bottom"/>
          </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Be sure that the parent element has enough space to hold all the items!**
Otherwise they will overlap each other

Comment: I use the two answer combine @Franco